# Is there any gain by lazy initialization of weights, biases and number of input channels for a convolution operation?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, pytorch, implementation, convolution

The basic layers for performing convolution operations [1](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.1/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html),[2](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.1/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html),[3](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.1/generated/torch.nn.Conv3d.html) in PyTorch are

```
nn.Conv1d:   Applies a 1D convolution over an input signal composed of several input planes.

nn.Conv2d:   Applies a 2D convolution over an input signal composed of several input planes.

nn.Conv3d:   Applies a 3D convolution over an input signal composed of several input planes.
```

Along with them, there are lazy versions [1](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LazyConv1d.html),[2](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LazyConv2d.html),[3](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LazyConv3d.html) of each of the aforementioned layers. They are

```
nn.LazyConv1d:    A torch.nn.Conv1d module with lazy initialization of the in_channels argument of the Conv1d that is inferred from the input.size(1).

nn.LazyConv2d:    A torch.nn.Conv2d module with lazy initialization of the in_channels argument of the Conv2d that is inferred from the input.size(1).

nn.LazyConv3d:    A torch.nn.Conv3d module with lazy initialization of the in_channels argument of the Conv3d that is inferred from the input.size(1).
```

We can observe from the description of lazy layers that the `in_channels` argument undergoes lazy initalization. Along with it, the attributes that will be lazily initialized are `weight` and `bias`.

> [Lazy Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978759/what-is-lazy-initialization-and-why-is-it-useful) is a performance optimization where you defer
> (potentially expensive) object creation until just before you actually
> need it. Lazy initialization is primarily used to improve performance,
> avoid wasteful computation, and reduce program memory requirements

Since `in_channels`, `weight` and `bias` are undergoing lazy initialization in lazy convolution layers of PyTorch, I am guessing that there may be cases that the layers can perform convolution operation without the need of `in_channels`, `weight` and `bias` or bypassing some of them.

Am I guessing correct? Are there any cases in which convolution operation is said to be done without initializing weights or number of input channels?  If not, what is the gain we are getting by making such lazy initialization?

Is it purely an implementation technique to postpone initialization of those three quantities till the actual execution of the convolution operation in order to use resources minimally?